# a combination problem about "find the largest k"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations

For each integer $n\ge7$ , find the largest $k\in\mathbb{N_+}$ for which there exist $k$ subsets $M_1,M_2,\cdots,M_k$ of $M=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ ,
such that $\left|M_i\right|\ge3$ and $\left|M_i\cap M_j\right|=1$  for all $1\leq i<j\leq k$.

I've proved that if $n=7, k_\max=7$(quite easy), but I don't have any idea how to solve the question above.

So could you, please, give me some ideas?

proof for $n=7:$

Consider a graph $G$ with 7 nodes(each node represents an element in $M$).

Join two nodes together when the two elements they represent are in the same subset. It's easy to find that there is at most 1 edge between every 2 nodes. A $K_m$subgraph of $G$ represents an $m$-element subset of $M$. So each subset costs at least 3 edges, while there are at most$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
 7\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) $ edges in the graph. So we have
$$k≤\frac{
\left( \begin{array}{c}
 7\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) 
}{3}=7$$

example:$M_1=\{1,2,3\};M_2=\{1,4,5\};M_3=\{1,6,7\};\\M_4=\{2,4,6\};M_5=\{2,5,7\};M_6=\{3,4,7\};M_7=\{3,5,6\}$.

Comment: how did you show $k\leq7$ when $n=7$ ?

Comment: @73dsi What is $C(i, j)$?

Comment: @73dsi Please do not distribute the information about the problem to the comments but edit your question and add this information.

Comment: @73dsi You r comment is not clear. THere are a lots of graphos with 7 nodes. Which one should we consider and why? And please show us the example.

Comment: @miracle173 I've edited my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The $n=k=7$ case is the [Fano Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane).